# how to use more than one button with Tab fragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tabs

I am creating a simple application. I am trying to store the data in SQLite db. I am getting no error. But, I feel I have messed up with brackets and or nesting of Inner classes . I have 3 buttons- Date Picker, Time picker and Create Account. UI is working fine. I checked the db code (by creating other project), that is also working fine . But, In this application, after clicking on create account, it doesn't show the message -'Data successfully saved' or if I leave the fields vacant , then also its not showing the message- "fields vacant". So, I feel I have done some wrong with this particular code. I am following an online tutorial. Could You please check and modify the code for me?

TabFragment1.java

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment   {

    TextView textViewTitle;
    EditText editTextName;
    EditText editTextBuy;
    EditText editTextHome;
    EditText editTextStore;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    EditText editTextPhone;
    EditText editTextDate;
    Button buttonCreateAccount;
    Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
    EditText txtDate, txtTime;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

    DataBaseAdapter dataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

        /*
        get Instance  of Database Adapter
        dataBaseAdapter= new DataBaseAdapter(getContext());
        */

        dataBaseAdapter = new DataBaseAdapter(getActivity());
        dataBaseAdapter = dataBaseAdapter.open();

        // Get Refferences of Views
        textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        editTextName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextBuy = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextBuy);
        editTextHome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextHome);
        editTextStore = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextStore);
        editTextAddress = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
        editTextPhone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        editTextDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        buttonCreateAccount = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);

        btnDatePicker = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btnTimePicker = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        txtDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.in_date);
        txtTime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.in_time);


      /*  btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(this);*/
        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Get Current Date
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get Current Time
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        buttonCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String name = editTextMedicineName.getText().toString();
                String buy = editTextQuantityToBuy.getText().toString();
                String lHome = editTextLeftAtHome.getText().toString();
                String mStore = editTextMedicineStore.getText().toString();
                String mAdd = editTextMedStoreAddress.getText().toString();
                String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();
                String date = editTextDate.getText().toString();


                // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                if (name.equals("") || buy.equals("") || lHome.equals("") || mStore.equals("") || mAdd.equals("") || phone.equals("") || date.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Field Vacant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }


                else {
                    // Save the Data in Database
                    dataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(name, buy, lHome, mStore, mAdd, phone, date);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Reminder Successfully Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        dataBaseAdapter.close();
    }

}
```